# How to rigorously prove $E(X)=E(X|A)P(A)+E(X|A^c)P(A^c)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

X is a random variable while A is an event. I try to prove $$E(X)=E(X|A)P(A)+E(X|A^c)P(A^c)$$

Assuming $X$ is a continuous random variable, if $$E(X|A)=\int_{x\in A}xf_{X|A}(x)dx=\int_{x\in A}xf_{X,A}(x)/P(A)dx $$ $$E(X|A^c)=\int_{x\in A^c}xf_{X|A^c}(x)dx=\int_{x\in A^c}xf_{X,A^c}(x)/P(A^c)dx $$, and $f_{X,A}(x)=f_{X,A^c}(x)$ hold, then equality is obviously true. But the problem is I don't know whether the joint probability density function $f_{X,A}(x)$ is well defined here and if $f_{X,A}(x)=f_{X,A^c}(x)$ .

I've seen this conditional expectation equality somewhere and intuitively it makes good sense. But I hope to see a rigorous proof for it. Do I have to dig into measure theory to prove this? Thanks!

Comment: For avoiding mixing random variables and events, you could define $Y=I_A$ , i.e, the indicator variable of the event.

Comment: See *Total expectation theorem* on [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) or search in this site.